# Evaluating an outlook message inside another email with rules or addons

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Im trying to evaluate an email I recieve which has a message attached, using rules.
I wish to check the
To: "address"
field in the attachment ( which is in outlook message format ) then process that message and move it to a random folder. 
Is anyone aware of how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the .eml to one of your inbox folders, but I don't think there is a way to evaluate the original email based on the contents of the attached .eml.

Comment: I actually want to do this automatically